# Entity Framework constraint naming in database

Tags: entity-framework, migration, primary-key, constraints

I have a problem with the naming of some primary keys in the database. On my development system the primary key constraints are named `PK_FullTableName`. Now on a production system the constraints are all named `PK_PartofTableName_3214EC27164452B1` (with different Hex characters for each table).

The problem I have are the migrations. I have a code-based migration, that should change the primary key of a table and therefore has to drop the old constraint/primary key with `DropPrimaryKey("FullTableName", new[] { "Field1", "Field2" });`

On my development system everything works fine, on the productive system I get an SQL exception that the constraint `PK_FullTableName` could not be found and I cannot migrate.

I don´t know why Entity Framework names the constraints different on these two systems. Does anyone know what this behavior is depending on? Is this naming from the EF or from the database(MSSQLExpress)? And is there a workaround?

Comment: Work-around: for once change the generated names in the production system to the meaningful names you intend to use by a manually created SQl script or a script generated by a tool like Redgate. And always use named PK's in migration scripts afterwards. Maybe you have to renew the Migration-History table manually as well.